# Java - Sorting a 2D Array by Row Sum

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, jgrasp

Trying to write a method that swaps the rows of a 2D array in order of increasing row sum.

For example, if I have the following 2d array:

```
int [][] array = {4,5,6},{3,4,5},{2,3,4};
```

I would want it to output an array as so:

```
{2 3 4}, {3 4 5}, {4 5 6}
```

*Methodology:*

a.) take the sums of each row and make a 1D array of the sums

b.) do a bubble sort on rowSum array

**c.) swap the rows of the original array based on the bubble sort swaps made**

d.) then print the newly row sorted array.

Here's my code so far:

```
      public void sortedArrayByRowTot() {
        int [][] tempArray2 = new int [salaryArray.length [salaryArray[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray2.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < tempArray2[i].length; j++) {
            tempArray2[i][j] = salaryArray[i][j];
          }
        }

        int [] rowSums = new int [tempArray2.length];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray2.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < tempArray2[i].length; j++) {
            sum += tempArray2[i][j];
          }
          rowSums[i] = sum;
          sum = 0;
        }

        int temp;
        int i = -1;
        for(int j = rowSums.length; j > 0; j--){
          boolean isSwap = false;
          for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {
            if(rowSums[i-1] > rowSums[i]) {
              temp = rowSums[i-1];
              rowSums[i-1] = rowSums[i];
              rowSums[i] = temp;
              isSwap = true;
            }
          }

          if(!isSwap){
            break;
          }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < tempArray2.length; k++) {
          temp = tempArray2[i-1][k];
          tempArray2[i-1][k] = tempArray2[i][k];
          tempArray2[i][k] = temp;
        }

        for (int b = 0; b < tempArray2.length; b++) {
          for (int c = 0; c < tempArray2[b].length; c++) {
            System.out.print(tempArray2[b][c] + " ");
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Not sure if I am doing part c of my methodology correctly?

It keeps saying **"Exception in thread "main"** java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2"

Comment: please indent 4 spaces after every open brace.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> IntStream.of(a).sum()));`

Comment: @Tommy But why?

Comment: @Tommy That's not JavaDoc, it's an outdated Oracle style guide. If [2 spaces is good enough for Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.2-block-indentation), I think it's good enough for OP.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using a comparator? Thanks.

Comment: @Tommy Documentation != JavaDoc. I'm not saying anything changed. I'm saying that it's not part of Java's formal specification, like the JLS or JDK JavaDocs, and therefore doesn't have greater authority than another well-established convention, like Google's. For the record, I myself follow the more common convention of 4 spaces, but that doesn't mean I view it as an ultimate truth.

Comment: @shmosel Okay. I though you were saying 2 spaces was _the_ correct way, not _a_ correct way. I always do 4 spaces just because it looks nicer and easier to read, and that's what I was always taught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my question. Thanks.

```
    public void sortedArrayByRowTot() {
      //Creates tempArray2 to copy salaryArray into
      int [][] tempArray2 = new int [salaryArray.length][salaryArray[0].length];

      //Copies salaryArray into tempArray2
      for (int i = 0; i < salaryArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < salaryArray[i].length; j++) {
          tempArray2[i][j] = salaryArray[i][j];
        }
      }

      //Creates rowSum array to store sum of each row
      int [] rowSums = new int [tempArray2.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < tempArray2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempArray2[0].length; j++) {
          rowSums[i] += tempArray2[i][j];
        }
      }

      //Modified Bubble Sort of rowSum array (highest to lowest values)
      int temp;
      int i = 0;
      for(int j = rowSums.length; j > 0; j--){
        boolean isSwap = false;
        for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {
          if(rowSums[i-1] < rowSums[i]) {
            temp = rowSums[i-1];
            rowSums[i-1] = rowSums[i];
            rowSums[i] = temp;
            isSwap = true;
            //swaps rows in corresponding tempArray2 
            int [] temp2 = tempArray2[i-1];
            tempArray2[i-1] = tempArray2[i];
            tempArray2[i] = temp2;
          }
        }

        if(!isSwap){
          break;
        }
      }  

      //Prints sorted array 
      System.out.println("Sorted array: ");
      for (i = 0; i < tempArray2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempArray2[i].length; j++) {
          System.out.print("$"+ tempArray2[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @shmosel said, you can do it like this:

```
public static void sortedArrayByRowTot() {
    int [][] array = {{4,5,6},{3,4,5},{2,3,4}};
    Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> IntStream.of(a).sum()));
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using a comparator? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way. That I have solved.

```
 public class Solution{
          public static void sortedArrayByRowTot() {
            int [][] salaryArray = { {4,5,6},{3,4,5},{2,3,4} };
            int [][] tempArray2 = new int [salaryArray.length][salaryArray[0].length];

            for (int i = 0; i < salaryArray.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < salaryArray[i].length; j++) {
                tempArray2[i][j] = salaryArray[i][j];
              }
            }

            // Buble Sort to store rowSums
            int [] rowSums = new int [tempArray2.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < tempArray2.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < tempArray2[0].length; j++) {
                rowSums[i] += tempArray2[i][j];
              }
            }

            //Buble Sort by Rows Sum (Lowest Value to Highest)
            int temp;
            int i = 0;
            for(int j = rowSums.length; j > 0; j--){
              boolean isSwap = false;
              for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {
                if(rowSums[i-1] > rowSums[i]) {
                  temp = rowSums[i-1];
                  rowSums[i-1] = rowSums[i];
                  rowSums[i] = temp;
                  isSwap = true;
                  //swaps rows in corresponding tempArray2 
                  int [] temp2 = tempArray2[i-1];
                  tempArray2[i-1] = tempArray2[i];
                  tempArray2[i] = temp2;
                }
              }

              if(!isSwap){
                break;
              }
            }  
            /** No Need.
            for (int k = 0; k < tempArray2.length; k++) {
            temp = tempArray2[i-1][k];
            tempArray2[i-1][k] = tempArray2[i][k];
            tempArray2[i][k] = temp;
          }
          */

            for (int b = 0; b < tempArray2.length; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < tempArray2[b].length; c++) {
              System.out.print(tempArray2[b][c] + " ");
            }
          }
          }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            sortedArrayByRowTot();
        }
      }
```