# Sorting array contains some arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a array that contains arrays in it.
and I need to write a function that sort the little array on the big array( I mean the minimum sum of the little array is be the first on the index 0 and after the second on index1 and the maximum sum of the little array in in the end of the big aray =index bigArray.length-1

How  can I sort an array that contains  arrays in it?
i need to do that with no object or things like that. just regular and simple code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Fj3.png)

```
public static int [][] sum (int [][] arr) {

int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

        sum=sum+arr[i][j];

    }
```

Comment: You'd write a comparator.

Comment: And it also helps to think up a few example data sets. Then use a piece of paper and a pen and figure how you would sort these things "manually". Especially how you would compare the different entries in your array. And then you try put that in code.

Comment: i know what i want to do if i know all sum of which array i will do sort but how i compare all the arrays? u can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Sorting a 2D Array by Row Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993028/java-sorting-a-2d-array-by-row-sum)

Answer (score 1):

Since summing the inner array is a relatively time-consuming process, and the sum value is needed more than once when sorting, you should create an object to hold the array and the sum, e.g.

```
static class ArraySum implements Comparable<ArraySum> {
    final int[] array;
    final int sum;
    ArraySum(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
        this.sum = Arrays.stream(array).sum();
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ArraySum that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.sum, that.sum);
    }
}
```

Since it's `Comparable`, you can sort it directly, so with that in hand, you can easily sort the outer array using Java 8+ streams:

```
public static int[][] sort(int[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(ArraySum::new).sorted()
                 .map(a -> a.array).toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

That doesn't sort the input 2D array, but returns a new 2D array, i.e. a new outer array with the original inner arrays sorted.

*Test*

```
int[][] arr = { { 3, 5, 4 }, { 4, 3, 1, 2 }, { 5, 6 } };
int[][] arr2 = sort(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2));
```

*Output*

```
[[3, 5, 4], [4, 3, 1, 2], [5, 6]]
[[4, 3, 1, 2], [5, 6], [3, 5, 4]]
//    10         11        12     sum
```

As you can see, the original 2D array is unmodified, and the new array is sorted by the sum of the inner arrays.

Comment: i need to do that with no object or things like that. just regular and simple code...

Comment: @LiroyLevi No such constraints are listed in the question. This is the best performing solution, so I'm leaving it as-is, so others who might not have those constraints can find it.

Comment: ok Sorry I bothered you.thank u anyway =] if u can i will be glad that u will help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works perfectly, but it should definitely get you close.  I believe this is a buble sort technique.

```js
public static int [][] sum (int [][] arr) {
    
    //start at first array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        //sum of first array
        int sum1 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            sum1 += arr[i][j];
        }
        //compare to each of the arrays after
        for (int k = i+1; k < arr.length; k++) {
            int sum2 = 0;
            for (int l = 0; l < arr[k].length; j++){
                sum2 += arr[k][l];
            }
            //if second array is smaller, swap
            if (sum2 < sum1){
                //might need to change this part to do complete copy
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[k];
                arr[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Comment: i did something like that but i dont know how much little arrays the user will give me . i need to write function that do all that

Comment: This will loop through the entire length of the arrays.  As long as there are at least two to compare, it will go through them all.  If there's only one array, there will be an error, so you'd need an if statement to handle that case.  If there is only one array, then it's already sorted though.